# Microsoft Outlook not displaying background-image

Tags: php, joomla, outlook

I am using the joomla mail function. I have attached a background-image for the message body.

The image is displayed in all tools like: Gmail, Yahoo, Rediff etc.

But it does not show in Outlook 2007.

Seaching the internet, I did not get any information to let me know, wether the `img` tag is supported in Outlook

Comment: Sorry for necroposting :) Just in case anyone needs it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465922/1691640

Answer (score 0):

Background images are not supported in Outlook for any elements other than the body tag of an HTML email. The body of the email is not the same thing as it refers to the contents of the email and not the HTML body tag.

You might also look at this hack to enable background images in outlook - http://emailmarketingvoodoo.com/blog/post/outlook-2007-can-now-render-background-images/