# Issue to set background image in yahoo email

Tags: css, image, email

I set a `background image in email templates`. It's work fine when sending email to `Gmail` but when emails open in `yahoo`. Does not show the background image.

Any specific settings to show image in yahoo email.

Below my code of email template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body style="background: url(http://domain.com/images/abc.jpg) top; background-size:cover;">
    <div class="abc">
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Welcome</p>
        <p>Thanks</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have experience in it.

Answer (score 1):

I got a `solution`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="abc"  style="background-image: url(http://domain.com/images/abc.jpg); background-size:cover;">
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Welcome</p>
        <p>Thanks</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got perfect email in `gmail and yahoo` both.

Thanks who tried to sortout my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Yahoo the key is that the url uses single quotes (or perhaps double quotes if you have the attribute in single quotes).

So it has to be:

```html
<body style="background: url('http://example.com/images/abc.jpg') top;">
  ...
</body>
```

Without the single quotes in the url, the Yahoo parser will reject this bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes in the style attribute that either need to be escaped or changed to single quotes.

```
style="background: url('http://domain.com/images/abc.jpg') top; background-size:cover;"
```

Comment: ohh... no sorry...I mistake in copy.. There are no quotes issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to add a background image in HTML. When coding a background image for all email clients (even outlook) my code used to have a lot of fallbacks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body background="http://domain.com/images/abc.jpg" style="background: url('http://domain.com/images/abc.jpg') top; background-image:url('http://domain.com/images/abc.jpg');">
    <div class="abc">
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Welcome</p>
        <p>Thanks</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the one you were looking for was background-image.

Cheers

Comment: No sorry. Not worked. Why yahoo removed background image don't know.

Comment: try removing ` background-size:cover;` and see if that does anything?

Answer (score -1):

You can, currently, set it for Yahoo *and* Outlook, and Gmail too.
Just be sure to add absolute image paths.
Tested on Outlook 2016, can not tell about earlier versions.

Here's an example:

```
<div style="width: 300px;
height: 42px;
background: url('ribbon.png') no-repeat transparent;
margin: 0 auto;">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:300px;height:42px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="ribbon.png" color="#7bceeb" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    <![endif]-->
    <div>
         Some text for the div, that has BG behind it.
    </div>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```

Comment: The guy is using an absolute image path, and your example is using a relative path.

Answer (score -1):

For me, [user1780370's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62686503/17205163) was part of the solution. The main problem turned out to be using the forward slash syntax to denote background size as shown below.

```html
<div style="background: url('https://background.png') no-repeat center / cover;>
```

Apparently, Yahoo ["removes slash syntax values and makes the value invalid."](https://www.enovapoint.com/background-image-support-in-email-clients/).

The fix was to separate background size:

```html
<div style="
  background: url('https://background.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;"
>
```

Comment: This answer should be more of a comment not an answer. If the other answer is missing some information.