# Email HTML Template, showing background image and not as an attachment

Tags: html, css, background-image

In the email template that I am writing, I would like to have the image shown as my background image, because I would like to overlay some text on it.
The email working as expected in other email client, e.g. GMAIL, but not Yahoo. The background image become an attachment in the email.

I have tested below methods

```
<td colspan="3" style="background-image:url(cid:cover.png); background-size:cover;" align="center" width="600px" height="290" valign="top">
```

and

```
<td colspan="3" background="cid:cover.png" align="center" width="600px" height="290" valign="top">
```

and

```
<td colspan="3" style="background-image:url(cid:cover.png); background-size:600px 290px;" align="center" width="600px" height="290" valign="top">
```

and

```
.banner {
            background-image: url(cid:cover.png);
            background-size:600px 290px;
        }

<td colspan="3" class="banner" align="center" width="600px" height="290" valign="top">
```

The results are the same. Not sure if anyone have any other method I can try on.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried all solutions of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452403/issue-to-set-background-image-in-yahoo-email)

Comment: Thanks @SrushtiShah, yes, I tried the inline approach. as shown above

Comment: Are you still having issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(